# How to use part of the request in the next iteration of the loop controller of Jmeter to handle cumulative records request?

Tags: jmeter

How can I take a part of request and use it in the next request of Jmeter?

I'm trying to record an application where after logging in we have 100 rows displayed initially. When we scroll past 100 rows, a lazyloading call goes to the server and fetches 50 more records.

The call is in JSON format. For the first scroll it sends across all the 100 records as request and in response we get 50 new records. Now when we scroll beyond 150 records, the request takes all 150 records as request, and the response again returns 50 new records. The next scroll will send request with 200 records, cumulative.

Now I am trying to put a loop controller to do all the scrolling in the loop. Every lazyloading call will give only 50 records but for the next iteration of request cumulative number of records are sent as requests.

My intuition says to use a pre-processor and post-processor together for this. Since, I am new to Jmeter, I am not sure which pre-processor for this purpose or if there is any other alternative to solve this.

If default page response is, `fgAhi` and I need value `A` to pass in the first Json request. So the first request would be something like `xAy` and the response is `pBq`. Now for the second iteration I need the request to be `xABy` and response will be `pCq`. Third request will be `xABCy` and response be `pDq` and so on.

Here's an example:

Default page Response Body:

```
quiz: [{"question": "Question1","answer": "Answer1"},
{"question": "Question2","answer": "Answer2"},
{"question": "Question3","answer": "Answer3"},
{"question": "Question4","answer": "Answer4"}]
```

Loop Controller:
1st iteration of JSON request body:

```
quiz: [{"question": "Question1","answer": "Answer1"},
{"question": "Question2","answer": "Answer2"},
{"question": "Question3","answer": "Answer3"},
{"question": "Question4","answer": "Answer4"},getNextTwoQA]`
```

1st iteration response:

```
quiz: [{question": "Question5","answer": "Answer5"},
{question": "Question6","answer": "Answer6"}]`
```

2nd iteration of JSON request body:

```
quiz: [[{"question": "Question1","answer": "Answer1"},
{"question": "Question2","answer": "Answer2"},
{"question": "Question3","answer": "Answer3"},
{"question": "Question4","answer": "Answer4"},
{"question": "Question5","answer": "Answer5"},
{"question": "Question6","answer": "Answer6"},getNextTwoQA]
```

2nd iteration response:

```
quiz: [{question": "Question7","answer": "Answer7"},
{question": "Question8","answer": "Answer8"}]
```

3rd iteration of JSON request body:

```
quiz: [{"question": "Question1","answer": "Answer1"},
{"question": "Question2","answer": "Answer2"},
{"question": "Question3","answer": "Answer3"},
{"question": "Question4","answer": "Answer4"},
{"question": "Question5","answer": "Answer5"},
{"question": "Question6","answer": "Answer6"},
{question": "Question7","answer": "Answer7"},
{question": "Question8","answer": "Answer8"},getNextTwoQA]
```

3rd iteration response:

```
quiz: [{question": "Question9","answer": "Answer9"},
{question": "Question10","answer": "Answer10"}]
```

and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you only need post-processor, which saves the data you need as variable (cumulatively), and that variable is used in the body of the Sampler.

I.e. when first request returns `fgAhi`, post-processor saves `A` as `previousRows` variable (name was just selected as example, can be changed to anything else). Then inside the Loop, Sampler uses `${previousRows}` variable as part of its body. That Sampler also has post-processor that *alters* variable `previousRows` to add newly received result `B` to previously saved `A`. And since loop goes back to the same Sampler, it will automatically pick up a new value of `${previousRows}` on next iteration, which now is `AB`. And so on.

So basically the flow is like this:

```
First Sampler
  Post-Processor <-- gets data from first response
Loop Controller
  Scroll Sampler <-- uses `${previousRows}` as part of its request body
    Programmable Post-Processor <-- appends data to `${previousRows}`
```

After *Programmable Post-Processor* loop goes back to sampler, which uses new value for next iteration. By *Programmable Post-Processor* I mean any post-processor that allows you to write code. For example BeanShell Post-processor. The code to append data to `${previousRows}` would look something like this (a skeleton, specific data manipulations need to be added):

```
// Get current value of ${previousRows} variable
String previousRows = vars.get("previousRows");

// Get result returned by a sampler which contains new data
String newAddedRows = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
// you can manipulate response here in any way to get only required data

// Then append previousRows String and newAddedRows 
// and save as new value of ${previousRows} variable
// Showing simplest way here, you may need to do further manipulations:
vars.put("previousRows", previousRows + newAddedRows);
```

You can read about [BeanShell Post-Processor here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor)